# Clojure-refactor tweak namespace generation

Tags: emacs, clojure

In [clj-refactor](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el/wiki) there is the possibility to generate namespaces with `clj-add-ns-to-blank-clj-files`.

How do I tweak the namespace generation, for instance by adding metadata in the namespace: `(ns ^{:doc "" :author "nha"})`?

Comment: Seems that `cljr` uses yasnippet heavily. Did you try to modify snippet that generates ns form?

Comment: Basically [this one](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/9ce0b05f4b4d693831e67dd65d660716a8192e8d/clojure-mode/ns).

Comment: @OlegTheCat Ah I never used yasnippet - will have to try that thanks.